# Jsp adding numbers

Tags: java, html, jsp

How can i create a popup(alert) message when a user enters a correct value or an incorrect value by clicking on the "Go" button . i am not sure how to connect the "Go" button with the java code .

please help

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
 <body>

<% 
 int a =6;
 int b = 8; 
%>

<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="main.jsp">
 <%=a%>+<%=b%> =  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=num SIZE=20>
 <P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT value="Go"></p>
 <P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT value="Continue" disabled="disabled" ></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Nooooooooo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 1):

Once you're done removing all the scriptlets from your code...

You can make an alert appear when the button is clicked by doing something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="function(){ alert('hello, world'); }">
```

You probably won't get many responses because **using scriptlets with jsp is *extremely* frowned upon**.